# mysql histogram with negative values

Tags: mysql, histogram

I have a table like this:

```
ID | value
----------
1  |  -3 
2  |  -4
3  |   5
4  |   2
```

and I want to show histogram in mysql like this:

```
ID | value | histogram
-------------------------
1  |  -3   | ***
2  |  -4   |****
3  |   5   |    *****
4  |   2   |    **
```

I can't figure out how to represent the negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with some string manipulation monkey business.  But you will need to display the resulting text strings with a monospaced font. In many fonts, space characters take less space that star characters, so the zero-points won't line up right if you display these strings of stars that way.

First, the expression `IF(value<0, -value, 0)` will produce  `5` if `value` is `-5`, and otherwise zero.

Second, the expression `REPEAT('*', IF(value<0,-value,0))` will get you five stars in a row from that `-5` value, and no stars from any positive value.

Third, `REVERSE(RPAD(REPEAT('*', IF(value<0,-value,0)), 20, ' '))` will get you a 20-character-long text string ending in five stars in a row.  That's how you do the negative part of your little chart.

Finally, concatenate that to `REPEAT('*',IF(value<0,0,value))` to get something useful for positive instances of `value`.

This should do it for you.

```
SELECT id,
       value,
       CONCAT( REVERSE(RPAD(REPEAT('*', IF(value<0,-value,0)), 20, '=')),
               REPEAT('*',IF(value<0,0,value))
              ) AS histogram
  FROM t
 ORDER BY id
```

Notice that I hard-coded `20` as the largest negative value that will work here. You could do something more sophisticated if you needed to.